# How to simulate a TransportException in Symfony testing

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony6

I am writing tests for a small Symfony 6 project. The project contains a custom class representing a web form request. The class has methods for sending various emails using the Symfony MailerInterface. For example:

```
public function sendConfirmationEmail(): array
{
    if (!$this->validated) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Inquiry has not been validated. Use Inquiry->validate() first',
        ];
    }

    if (!$this->email) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Benutzer hat keine Emailadresse angegeben'
        ];
    }
    $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->to($this->email)
        ->subject('Eingangsbestätigung')
        ->htmlTemplate('confirmationEmail.html.twig')
        ->textTemplate('confirmationEmail.txt.twig')
        ->context([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'mail' => $this->email,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'subject' => $this->subject,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ]);

    try {
        $this->mailer->send($email);
        $this->logger->debug('Confirmation mail sent');

        return [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Email wurde gesendet',
        ];
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        $this->logger->debug('Error sending confirmation email: ' . $e);

        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Email konnte nicht gesendet werden: ' . $e,
        ];
    }
}
```

The `mailer` is passed to the constructor of the class as a read only variable:

```
public function __construct(
    private readonly LoggerInterface $logger,
    private readonly MailerInterface $mailer,
    private readonly array $officeRecipients,
    private readonly ValidatorInterface $validator,
) {
}
```

I have no trouble testing the successful cases using the Symfony `KernelTestCase` class, but I also want to test the `catch` block of the method in a unit test.

How can I simulate the `TransportException` during testing to trigger the `catch` block?

Comment: It seems to me that you can simulate this with a string that does not correspond to the standard e-mail format. Example : `test@123`.  In my memory this generates a `TransportException`.

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it seems as though I have backed myself into a corner here: the method only reaches the catch block if the Inquiry has been validated (using the ValidatorInterface). But validation does not accept non-standard email addresses, so it would fail.
I was thinking I could mock a custom MailerInterface for testing, which always throws a TransportException, but then I would have to relax the readonly requirement in the constructor.

Comment: Damn ... I hope for you that someone will have something to test. Good continuation ! :)